# How do I balance skill/luck in a forum game?

Tags: board-game

I am trying make a forum game where members of the forum can play daily, with role-playing elements, and tactical decisions. I've hosted werewolf games before, but I want this to be a little more involved. Mt new venture is a U-Boat game, where 10 members of the forum can sign up.  The game takes places in several phases, such as Patrol, Intercept, Attack, Evasion, Re-engage/Escape. In each phase the forum spits out some situations based on random numbers generated by the forum. The players make decisions and the results of their decisions advance the game to the next phase (or not).

For example: in the Patrol phase, the players basically roleplay, chat, and BS...entertain themselves. Each day the random number generator cranks out a number for contact. Let's say the RNG spits out a 90, which means enemy convoy spotted. (89 and less, no contact; 90 and up = contact).

The game moves to the Intercept phase, and the RNG spits out a number that tells the player the course of the convoy. In simple terms, the convoy can be moving away from the U-boat, parallel, towards, etc.

**Here's where I need help:** the players should make some kind of decision, such as "flank speed toward the convoy", "flank speed 45 degrees port" to intercept a convoy on a parallel course, etc. Now, how do I grade the decision?

How do I construct it so that the smarter/safer his choice, the better the results? Obviously, I cannot use the RNG for the outcome, there has to be some way to balance his skill in making a good decision.

Anyone have any ideas? I apologize if this is not the right place to ask this type of question.
thanks!
Neal

Comment: Can we salvage this question somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are game mechanics.

Game mechanics are rules which govern how a game works. They usually consist of three things:

1. Variables which make up the game state. Some variables might be known to the player (like their current depth, position and heading or obvious damage to their boat), some might be hidden (whether or not the enemy has already spotted them or non-obvious damage to their ship).
2. Actions each participant in the game (player or NPC) can perform, which have a different chance of succeeding depending on the variables and which then change the variables depending on whether or not they are successful.
3. Win- and lose conditions, which are combinations of variables which cause one player to win or lose the game. In the context of an u-boat RPG, a lose-condition could be that all crewmembers are either dead or left the ship. The win-condition could be to fulfill some mission and return to a friendly port.

The goal of every player is to perform actions to alter the game state variables in a way that their win-condition occurs and their lose-condition does not occur.

Variables you could trace are distance to target, current heading and speed of target and u-boat, depth of u-boat, damage to either ship etc.. How far you want to go into detail depends on how much realism you want and how much bookkeeping you are willing to do. For narrative RPGs it is often better to not go too far into detail to still leave room for imagination, improvisation and narrative freedom (having a game mechanic which governs when the first ship appears, is for example something I would not make a game mechanic for, so you retain the narrative freedom to decide to make a ship appear the moment you notice that the game becomes dull and needs some action).

Possible actions the player could perform is change their heading and/or speed or change their depth. They could fire their weapons, where the success chance depends on the current game state. I don't know much about naval warfare, but I would assume that the current distance to the target is at least one variable which would be important for the probability to hit the target with a torpedo. There could also be other variables which are more or less important (size of target, what kind of torpedo, experience of crew, weather and ocean currents, phase of the moon, whatever).

One question you need to ask yourself is: **Do you want the players to know your game mechanics?**

Some mechanics should be shared because they are character knowledge, like for example the minimum, optimum and maximum range of their weapons. These are things every real-life u-boat captain should know about, so your players should know them too.

But when you reveal too much about how the game works, the players will focus less on the roleplaying experience and more on the metagaming. Smart players will be more concerned with finding loopholes in your rules which give them an unrealistic advantage than with figuring out what their character would do in the current situation.

But when they do not know about your rules, they might feel cheated when events don't turn out the way they expect them to. You will also have a bit of a communication problem because players aren't aware of what actions actually have a meaning for your game mechanic and might talk at great length about details of their actions which you don't actually simulate while not saying anything about those details which actually matter. You can control that by asking specific questions ("do you go to *slow* speed, *medium* speed or *high* speed?"), but then you risk revealing too much about your mechanics which you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Although the Q is closed this is actually not a bad topic. A bit of luck always makes a game interesting but not so much that it becomes random. The actually ratio luck/game mechanics used in actual games is the result of considerations like you did. I wish there would be a better question so this answer does not get lost.

Comment: If everyone understands what the question is trying get at...what's wrong with simply answering it?

Comment: @Neal Aren't you satisfied with the answer I gave you? Anything you would have expected instead?